# How to rename a java class and it's usages with Mercurial support?

Tags: mercurial

when you rename a java file, it's class definition in file and it's usages should be changed.
does mercurial support this feature? 
I'm using Intellij Idea  and unfortunately it doesn't support mercurial. I want to track rename task with mercurial completely similar to all Idea does with subversion. can anybody help me?

thanks lot

Answer (score 6):

I don't know anything about IntelliJ, but I know something about the command line which I hope will help you.

You can use

```
hg addremove --similarity 90
```

on the command line to make Mercurial look at your files and search for renames. By setting the similarity parameter to a value less than 100, you tell Mercurial that is should treat almost-similar files as renames.

So if `Foo.java` has disappeared from the filesystem and `Bar.java` has appeared, then Mercurial will be able to figure out that `Foo.java` was simply renamed to `Bar.java` while updating the class name from `Foo` to `Bar`.

Use `hg status -C` to double-check the file status after running addremove.